SVGO CLI how to check SVGs from multiple folders
I am using the SVGO CLI script for transforming some icons.
The structure is - assets/icons/dark-mode and assets/icons/light-mode
I need to go across two folders and the structure of the output should be in the same way
I tried two variants:

svgo -f assets/icons -o icons --config=svgo.config.js
But it says that - "No svg files have been found".
Then if I change to - svgo -f assets/icons/* -o icons --config=svgo.config.js
It goes through two folders but makes output not in the same way
P.s. The names of svg are same so second folder icons override from first one

cp -R assets/icons icons && find icons -name '*.svg' -type f -exec svgo --config svgo.config.js {} \
This script works and makes output that I need, but it doesn't apply my config file



If I understand correctly, you have a directory structure as follows:
.
└── assets
    └── icons
        ├── dark-mode
        │   └── original.svg
        └── light-mode
            └── original.svg

You should be able to make this work with the following command:
svgo -f assets -r -o optimized-assets


-f for folder, to choose the directory of SVGs to optimize.
-r for recursive, to go through the directory recursively.
-o for output, to output to a new directory named out.
You may pass --config to use your custom config.

After running the command, the directory tree now looks like:
.
├── assets
│   └── icons
│       ├── dark-mode
│       │   └── original.svg
│       └── light-mode
│           └── original.svg
└── optimized-assets
    └── icons
        ├── dark-mode
        │   └── original.svg
        └── light-mode
            └── original.svg

